# .NET Core + React template rendering doesn't update after changes made

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I'm working with a .NET Core + React project (`dotnet new react`), and am testing out how pages render by just adjusting the default components and views that it starts out with. I adjusted the default component text (not code), just to see if it'll display my changes. For example, changing their `Hello World` to something else. However, none of my changes showed up. It just continues to display the default/original text.

I've tried doing `dotnet restore` prior to `dotnet run`, and tried changing the default text in a couple of the component .tsx files. But none of the files displayed the update. For some reason, when my friend opens up my project on their computer, they're able to see my changes. I tried hard refreshing and clearing my cache too, in case it was a cache issue, but still nothing.

I can't figure out why it's not working. This is my first time working with React. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I've been working with VS Code for this. When I open up my project in VS Community (and create a solution file for it), it displays the updates! However, if I have a project with no solution file, it still doesn't display the updates. Is there a specific extension or something I need for VS Code in order for it to work?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to `Development`.

In the same session `dotnet run` is being called,

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
```

When not set, the environment will default to `Production`. 
Looking at the generated `Startup.cs`, hot module replacement is only enabled when it's set to `Development`.

There is probably a way to set this value in VS Code without need to set it via command line.